# wp_get_attachment_image_src() does not return what I want

Tags: images

I got this annoying issue I can't solve :

```
if( $meta1 = '' && $meta2 = '' ) { 
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), my_own_size_function());
echo  $image_attributes[0];
} elseif(  $meta1 != '' ) { 
    echo $meta1; 
} elseif ( $meta2  != '' ){
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), my_own_size_function() );
    echo $image_attributes[0];
} else {
    echo "ko";
}
```

when I print_r `my_own_size_function()` I get an array like this :

```
Array
(
     [0] => 600
     [1] => 400
)
```

But when I print_r `$image_attributes`I get another result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/my_image.jpg
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 150
    [3] => 
)
```

Any idea of what can be the reason for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is entirely based on experiment over the last 15 minutes or so, so I wouldn't call it canonical but ...

`wp_get_attachment_image_src()` uses the [`image_downsize()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/media.php#L136) function, which  will attempt to find and return the [image closest in size to the supplied size values](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/media.php#L511). If you experiment with know image sizes (look at the actual images saved to `wp-content/uploads`) you will see what I mean. Despite the name, it will sometimes return larger images but the height and width components of the array should be set to the supplied values, or to some attempt at a scaled approximation (so it seems) if those values are wildly inaccurate. I can't tell if that "scaling" is what is happening in your case but it might be and it seems likely.

Let me give an example. I have an image that saved as 150x150, 293x300, and full size. This...

```
var_dump(wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array(20, 20)));
```

... returns an array with the 150x150 image and the sizes that I supplied-- 20x20. However this...

```
var_dump(wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array(200, 250)));
```

... returns the 150x150 image URL but with 200x204 for the sizes. That is not what I supplied. The size values have been altered by some algorithm. On further investigation it seem like [`image_constrain_size_for_editor`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/media.php#L36) is the more likely candidate.

You may also check to see if anything has applied a function to the [`image_downsize`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/media.php#L148) filter, as that will completely hijack the function.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Good read anyway but the problem is the size does not even change. I've include a size selector for featured image. It does not seem to come from `my_own_size_function()` simply because I get what I want when I print_r

Comment: I guess I'm the weakest link! I checked uploads and I was dealing with the only image who has not the appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function `my_own_size_function()`; to `array(600, 400)`

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array(600, 400));
```

Comment: Thanks dude but this would be `array(600,400)` instead. Anyway I already tried that but I checked the function in codex and they say `$size` can be an array, my function already return `array(600,400);`

Comment: And you have the image in that size uploaded?